# Why do I get "foreman: command not found" only in a directory *with* a Procfile?

Tags: foreman

I am on CentOS.  I've installed foreman with yum

In my home directory, with no Procfile I get:

```
$ foreman start
ERROR: Procfile does not exist.
```

However when I cd into a directory that has a Procfile, for example:

```
cd ~/supersender
```

Then the foreman command is unavailable, i.e. `forem [tab][[tab]` does not complete and I get

```
$ foreman start
-bash: foreman: command not found
```

Comment: You didn't install `foreman` in a directory that's in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I suspect you installed it in your home directory, and have `.` in your `$PATH`. So it only works when you're in your home directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem earlier.
In one recent project folder, I was able to run 'foreman start', but in an older folder I got:

```
$ foreman start
-bash: foreman: command not found
```

I suppose adding 'foreman' to the PATH should work too, but the following commands work for me:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall foreman
$ sudo gem install foreman
$ which foreman
/Users/liwen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/foreman
```

I still do not know the discrepancy in seeing 'foreman' between the recent the the old folders earlier, but the above works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem after installing foreman globally via `gem install foreman`.

I had installed it whilst using Ruby 2.7.1 (via `rvm`), but my project uses Ruby 3.1.0, so it couldn't find it.

Switching to 3.1.0, then installing again fixed it for me.

```
rvm use 3.1.0 && gem install foreman
```

Comment: for rbenv use "rbenv local 3.0.4 && gem install foreman'

Answer (score 4):

#### macOS

I fixed this by installing `foreman` using `brew`:

```bash
brew install foreman
```